# Filtering 2d Array / Returning ArrayIndexOutofBoundException

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

This is the structure of my 2d array along with the single array

```
public String[] sList() {
    String list[] = { "Asia Medic Family Hospital and Medical Center",
            "Adventist University of the Philippine Health Service ",
            "Bautista Hospital",
            "Catalan Medical Hospital ", 
            "Catbagan General Hospital",
            "Cavite Center for Mental Health", 
            "Cavite Doctors' Medical Center, Inc",
            "Cavite Medical Center", 
            "Cavite Municipal Hospital",
            "Cavite Naval Hospital", 
            "Contreras Medical Clinic",
            "Crisostomo General Hospital", 
            "DBB Municipal Hospital",
            "DLSU-Dr. Rodolfo Poblete Memorial Hospital ", 
            "De La Salle University Medical Center",
            "Del Rosario Hospital" };
return list;
.....
public String[][] sSpecialty() {
    String list[][] = { 



            {"Specialty 1.0", "Specialty1.1", "Specialty1.2" , " " , " " },
            {"Specialty 2.0", "Specialty2.1", "Specialty2.2" , " " , " "},
            {"Specialty 3.0", "Specialty3.1", "Specialty3.2", "Specialty3.3", " " },
            {"Specialty 4.0", "Specialty4.1", "Specialty4.2", "Specialty4.3", "Specialty4.4" },
            {"Specialty 5.0", "Specialty5.1", "Specialty5.2", "Specialty5.3", "Specialty5.4" },
            {"Specialty 6.0", "Specialty6.1", "Specialty6.2", "Specialty6.3", "Specialty6.4" },
            {"Specialty 7.0", "Specialty7.1", "Specialty7.2", "Specialty7.3", "Specialty7.4" },
            {"Specialty 8.0", "Specialty8.1", "Specialty8.2", "Specialty8.3", "Specialty8.4" },
            {"Specialty 9.0", "Specialty9.1", "Specialty9.2", "Specialty9.3", "Specialty9.4" },
            {"Specialty 10.0", "Specialty10.1", "Specialy10.2", "Specialty10.3", "Specialty10.4" },
            {"Specialty 11.0", "Specialty11.1", "Specialty11.2", "Specialty11.3", "Specialty11.4" },
            {"Specialty 12.0", "Specialty12.1", "Specialty12.2", "Specialty12.3", "Specialty12.4" },
            {"Specialty 13.0", "Specialty13.1", "Specialty13.2", "Specialty13.3", "Specialty13.4" },
            {"Specialty 14.0", "Specialty14.1", "Specialty14.2", "Specialty14.3", "Specialty14.4" },
            {"Specialty 15.0", "Specialty15.1", "Specialty15.2", "Specialty15.3", "Specialty15.4" },
            {"Specialty 16.0", "Specialty16.1", "Specialty16.2", "Specialty16.3", "Specialty16.4" }
};
return list;
```

How can I filter these 2d array, example I have an item here when I select Specialty2.2 the result is Adventist University of the Philippine Health Service ,as you can see they're both in 2nd array list. Im fine filtering single array but encounter problem when I add 2d array.

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < sList.length; loop++) {
        String temp = sTuition[loop];
        theTuitionFee = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        // ALL filter selected
        if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[5])
                ) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
```

Im getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in this part " && sSpecialty[loop][loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[5]) " any suggestions how can I get rid of this problem.

Here's the full program when I only use single array if you have any other way to add the created 2d array.

```
public class SchoolListFragmentFilter extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener {
NavigationDrawer navi = new NavigationDrawer();
String thisFilter[] = NavigationDrawer.theFilter;
int amountTF = NavigationDrawer.TuitionFee;
PSManilaDB conn = new PSManilaDB();
String sList[] = conn.sList();
String sReg[] = conn.sRegAffil();
String sAdmin[] = conn.sAdmin();
String sType[] = conn.sSize();
String sAmbience[] = conn.sAmbience();
String sTuition[] = conn.sTuitionFee();
int theTuitionFee;

ListView lvList;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> schoolIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_school_list, container, false);
    lvList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSchools);
    for (int loop = 0; loop < sList.length; loop++) {
        String temp = sTuition[loop];
        theTuitionFee = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        // ALL filter selected
        if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // RegAffil
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // Administration
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // RoomAmbience
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // Tuition Fee
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // regAffil and admin
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // regAffil and type
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // regaffil and ambience
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // reg afill and tuition
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and type
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and ambience
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and tuition
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // type and ambience
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // type and tuition
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // ambience and tuition
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

        }
    }
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    schoolIndex.clear();
    ArrayList<String> finalFilterList = list;
    ArrayList<String> finalSchoolsList = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(this.sList));
    for (int i = 0; i < finalFilterList.size(); i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < finalSchoolsList.size(); o++) {
            if (finalFilterList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(
                    finalSchoolsList.get(o))) {
                schoolIndex.add(o);
            }
        }
    }
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Schools Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        navi.dia.show();
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int indx = schoolIndex.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    Intent woahIntent = new Intent("capstone.app.recommender.SCHOOLINFO");
    woahIntent.putExtra("key", indx);
    startActivity(woahIntent);
}
// && sAdmin[count].equals(thisFilter[1])
// && sType[count].equals(thisFilter[2]))
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `sList.length` is 16, but your 2d array width is only 5. This means that `loop` goes up to 16, but the second index in `sSpecialty[loop][loop]` must be less than 5. This is where you get the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I presume you need to replace the if statement with something like

```
// ALL filter selected
boolean filtermatch=false;

for(int subloop=0;subloop<sSpecialty[loop].length;subloop++){
        if (sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[5])
                ) {
                   filtermatch=true;
        }
}

if(filtermatch && sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee;){
    list.add(sList[loop]);
}
```

The second loop keeps the second index within bounds.

Comment: You analyze it well and you're right but still getting same error, in fact I have 58 items each here. Is there any other way ?

Comment: What's the size of `thisFilter`?

Comment: It's in another class and the size "public static String theFilter[] = new String[6];" . and I call it here located in my post "String thisFilter[] = NavigationDrawer.theFilter;"

Comment: problem already solved ! You give me an idea to create subloop to holds all values of the columns .
for(int subloop=0; subloop<sSpecialty[loop].length; subloop++) {
  and add this
     && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
    list.add(sList[loop]);