# Removing duplicate items in ArrayList Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

How can I remove duplicate items in my ArrayList. I am new in android programming and I also tried to study other but it really hard for me to figure out how to eliminate similar items. Some suggestion are using hashmap but I have no idea where to put it. Here's my code.

```
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    schoolIndex.clear();
    ArrayList<String> finalFilterList = list;
    ArrayList<String> finalSchoolsList = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(this.sList));
    for (int i = 0; i < finalFilterList.size(); i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < finalSchoolsList.size(); o++) {
            if (finalFilterList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(
                    finalSchoolsList.get(o))) {
                schoolIndex.add(o);
            }
        }
    }
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Hospitals Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        navi.dia.show();
    }
    return v;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicates, you can add all elements to a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and then add them back to the ArrayList but **you will lose the order** if you use a Set.

As you are using the ArrayList in adapter, I suggest you to use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which retains the order

Try this :

```
      List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // this will be your arraylist
      LinkedHashSet<String> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
      linkedHashSet.addAll(arrayList);
      arrayList.clear();
      arrayList.addAll(linkedHashSet);
```

Comment: Already found this answer earlier but didn't notice it's efficiency in my program. Thumbs up for you bud . Anyway is there anyway how can I contact you since I'm new in android programming.

Comment: @carljohnsantos I am glad that you found it :) By the way you don't need to specifically contact me for help , **Help will always be given at StackOverflow to those who ask for it.** ;)

Comment: @carljohnsantos the same way you have done this ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245675/filtering-2d-array-returning-arrayindexoutofboundexception

There will be a `tick(correct)` symbol below the score, you have to mark it.

Comment: Is it the star icon on my post ? No idea how I marked my previous post , sorry sir.

Comment: I see sorry , hehe the arrow up in your comment . I already did , thanks

Comment: @carljohnsantos no issues :) and I am no sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Duplicates likes this:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>('Your ArrayList');

// Then you can create a new ArrayList, this will be a list with no duplicates
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Sorry if this does not answer the question

Comment: You're a big help budd but there's another issue , the items were not in alphabetical order .

Comment: @carljohnsantos I was thinking about the same and just updated my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, well sorry about that. Atleast @karthik was able to help you out :).